# Why is IdlingResource null in Espresso tests on Android API 22?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

**EDIT:** I've tested the below on two devices on Android API 22 and one on API 19, the one on API 19 does not have the issue. Any ideas what the difference could be between versions?

I am setting up espresso tests for my Android with an IdlingResource identical to the example [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/IdlingResourceSample).

My Test setup:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mMainActivity =
        new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class);

private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;

@Before
public void registerIdlingResource() {
    mIdlingResource = mMainActivity.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(mIdlingResource);
}
```

In my Activity each time I change the Idle state I call:

```
if (mIdlingResource != null) {
    mIdlingResource.setIdleState(false);
} else {
    Log.d("error ", "idle resource is null");
}
```

My issue comes when trying to change the idle state in my activity -- there seems to be a lag between when the activity is created and the IdlingResource is available.

**In the first test of the sequence, the IdlingResource is never available** -- as such I cannot set the initialValue of the IdlingResource to false and then later switch back to true. That seems to be caused by the annotation lifecycle as described in [this article](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-testing-part-1-espresso-basics-7219b86c862b):

[image]

From what I can tell the Activity is created by the @Rule and then the IdlingResource is instantiated in the @Before. Since the Activity is already running the idle resource is null at each of the points where I attempt to change the state.

In subsequent tests only the first instance of setIdleState (which occurs in the onCreate) is skipped -- perhaps something to do with the Activity lifecycle with the @Rule? -- but the others operate as expected.

Is there a best practice to getting the @Rule and @Before to work in order before the first test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution to this issue of the activity launching before the IdlingResource is available is to set the Rule so that it does not launch the activity. The benefit of this method is that you do not have to manually register the IdlingResource in the Activity.

To make implement this solution, use the following constructor of ActivityTestRule

`ActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode, boolean launchActivity)`

So the code would look like:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mMainActivity =
        new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class, false, true);

private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;

@Before
public void registerIdlingResource() {
    mIdlingResource = mMainActivity.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(mIdlingResource);
    mMainActivity.launchActivity(new Intent());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `static IdlingResource` in your activity. Initialize the `mIdlingResource` before starting background tasks (I'm not including the code for initialization since you have already written it).

```
private static IdlingResource mIdlingResource;

//Getter for mIdlingResource
public IdlingResource getmIdlingResource() {
    return mIdlingResource;
}
```

Then you can access this static resource from your test instead of creating a new variable.

```
@Before
public void registerIdlingResource() {
    IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(mMainActivity.getActivity().getmIdlingResource());
}
```

Then `mIdlingResource` will not be null in the Activity.

**Note** - Google advises the use of CountingIdlingResource. You can find the implementation here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource

**UPDATE**:
After checking the code in the comments.

Your IdlingResource is getting created when you're calling it for the first time while registering.

Just call `getIdlingResource()` once in `onCreate()` of your activity (or before you call `setIdleState`). Leave the rest of the code same. It won't create duplicates because a `null` check is performed before initializing.

Comment: This does not seem to solve my issue. On the first test the `@Rule` starts the activity and therefore the background tasks before the `@Before` is run which is where the idling resource is initialized

Comment: With that in mind I've tried on three devices and the one that is API 19 works with your solution, while the two that are API 22. Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: Can you please post the code where you have initialized the `IdlingResource`? I checked with API 19, 23 and 26 (with CountinIdlingResource) and they are all working fine.

Comment: It is initialized exactly the same as in the example here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/IdlingResourceSample/MainActivity.java#L80

Comment: Your `IdlingResource` is getting created when you're calling it for the first time while registering. Just call `getIdlingResource()` once in `onCreate()` of your activity (or before you call `setIdleState`). Leave the rest of the code same. It won't create duplicates because a null check is there.

Comment: Won't that then initialize the `IdlingResource` in Production as well?

Comment: "When adding idling resources into your app, we highly recommend performing only the registration and unregistration operations in your tests and placing the idling resource logic itself in your app's production code."
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource

Comment: Ah i see, it seems that the samples are a bit outdated then